# TestCafe - Can selectors / assertions be run in parallel?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I attempted to benchmark running times but couldn't get a conclusive result.

Is there any difference between:

```
await t.expect(Selector('something').visible).ok()
await t.expect(Selector('something1').visible).ok()
await t.expect(Selector('something2').visible).ok()
```

and

```
Promise.all([
    t.expect(Selector('something1').visible).ok(),
    t.expect(Selector('something2').visible).ok(),
    t.expect(Selector('something3').visible).ok()
])
```

?

It appears as though in each case the assertions are run serially.

Note: I ask to see whether actions and assertions on multiple matching yet independent elements can be sped up, I understand in most cases we want tests to run synchronously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TestCafe has internal commands queue, which is used to form a chain of all test controller API calls. So you are right, there should be no difference between a set of serial `await`ed assertions and `Promise.all`. Currently you have to move all code that fetches data from the browser in a single [ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/clientfunction/) to achieve parallel data acquisition for a number of elements.